# React toggling between clickable words that pull up <Elements/>

Tags: reactjs, toggle, element

Somewhat new to React.
I want to be able to toggle between React elements CreateUser, EditUser, and ListUser.
It would be great to have a clickable text that when selected pulls up that element and its
corresponding stuff. In the case of Create its a field with a save button.

What is the best way to have my CrudSelector class list all three texts, make them clickable and pull up the stuff inside toggling to the selected one at a time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Always a good idea to share code with your question.

You'll want to use some kind of state which tells your parent component which child component to show. Kind of like this in your React functional component:

```
const [ featureToShow, setFeatureToShow ] = useState('list')

return (
  <>
    {/* Show some buttons to change the state */}
    <button onClick={() => setFeatureToShow('list')}>Show User List</button>
    <button onClick={() => setFeatureToShow('create')}>Create User</button>
    <button onClick={() => setFeatureToShow('edit')}>Edit User</button>
    
    {/* Depending on what is in the state show that component */}
    { featureToShow === 'list' ? <ListUser /> : null }
    { featureToShow === 'create' ? <CreateUser /> : null }
    { featureToShow === 'edit' ? <EditUser /> : null }
  </>
)
```

In reality you'll probably want to enable clicking on the user's name in ListUser to show the EditUser component.